# Magento products disappear from Category

Tags: magento-1.9

We're having an issue with usually just one product disappearing from a category in Magento.

We will add products to a category, and they will be there, and then when we get a lot of traffic, one item will disappear.

I traced the sql that pulls the products on the category page:

`` SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`
, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`
, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`
, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`
, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`
, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`
, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`
, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`is_imported`, `e`.`ugiftcert_amount_config`
, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`
, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`
, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`
, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` 
FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
        ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 
            AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '908' 
            AND cat_index.is_parent=1
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` 
        ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' 
        AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 
ORDER BY `cat_index_position` ASC, `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 99 ``

I exported the data from those three tables when I saw a product missing, and the product was in catalog_product_flat_1 and catalog_category_product_index, but was not in catalog_product_index_price.

The way I fix this is just by saving the product in the back end, which fixes the table, and product shows in Category.

So obviously this is an indexing issue. I am having trouble tracking down where catalog_product_index_price gets updated and/or created? And also what causes the reindex?

I found this post: *[Magento EE: Missing products in catalog_product_index_price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373381/magento-ee-missing-products-in-catalog-product-index-price)* But that is for configurable products, the ones that disappear for me are simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!